java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors Error
Hello I have just downloaded mallet (Mac OS) and when I input "./bin/mallet import-dir --help" into the command line I get this error message:
Error: Could not find or load main class cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors
Does anyone know how to fix this?
I input into the command line "./bin/mallet import-dir --help" and always get this error.
Error: Could not find or load main class cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors
The tutorial I was using (https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/topic-modeling-and-mallet#mac-instructions) said this command should produce a list of variables for importing documents.
